# Form data not saving to database on form loaded from different controller / view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

Sorry for the vague title.

I want to enable comments on a post / comments type system (in my case snags and snag comments).

I have a snags table, a snag_comments table and a has many / belongs to relationship between snag and snag comments.

On the show page for each snag I have a form rendering for snag comments. When I submit the form, it redirects to the root url and doesn't save anything to the snag_comments table.

This is all the information I get:

```
Started POST "/snag_comments" for ::1 at 2019-05-07 12:53:16 +0100
Processing by SnagCommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yBefFfnI289UXqQYzF37DBRGQSk2Uqu41/OQO/mnET9aj2S3OqjLmSGtgyyZkTDz0aSdKzSPofQNeSzx/UH3ng==", "snag_comment"=>{"snag_id"=>"183", "content"=>"sdfgfsdgsdfgds"}, "commit"=>"Send"}
  Resident Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "residents".* FROM "residents" WHERE "residents"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "residents"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :redirect_residents rendered or redirected
```

So my params are going through. I don't know why it's not saving to the database.

In my snags controller I have:

```
def show
  @snag_attachments = @snag.snag_attachments.all
  @snag_comment = SnagComment.new
  @snag_comments = SnagComment.where(snag_id: @snag.id)
end
```

And my snag comments controller (which is currently incomplete while I figure out this broken part):

```
class SnagCommentsController < ApplicationController
  skip_authorization_check
  before_action :set_parent

  def create
    @snag_comment = SnagComment.new(snag_comment_params)
    if @snag_comment.save
      redirect_to snags_path
    end
  end

  private

  def set_parent
    @parent = @snag
  end

  def snag_comment_params
    params.require(:snag_comment).permit(:content, :image, :snag_id,
                                         :commenter, :first_name, :last_name)
  end
end
```

The form which is rendered (views/snag_comments/_form):

```
<div class="snag-comment-form">
  <%= simple_form_for snag_comment, url: snag_comments_path do |f| %>
    <% if snag_comment.errors.any? %>
      <div class="submission-errors">
        <ul>
          <% snag_comment.errors.full_messages.each do |error_msg| %>
            <li>
              <%= fa_icon "exclamation-circle" %>
              <%= error_msg %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :snag_id, value: @snag.id %>
    <%= f.input :content, label: false, as: :text, placeholder: t(".content"), maxlength: 1000, required: true, class: "snag-comment-content" %>

    <div class="snag-comment-submit">
      <%= f.submit t(".send"), class: "btn branded-btn send" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And where the form is called from (views/homeowners/snags/show):

```
<%= render 'snag_comments/form', snag_comment: @snag_comment %>
```

I need the snag comments to be outside of the homeowner module because it also needs to be accessible to the admin module (admin and homeowner can comment on the same snags).

I can't figure out why the form is redirecting and not saving. I have tried removing any redirect and just specifying that the form should be saved but it still redirects to root url and doesn't save, so something must be going wrote between passing the params and actually saving.

Comment: Are you declaring a `root` route in `config/routes.rb`> If so, did you make sure to put it at the bottom of the list? The order matters.

Comment: `@parent = @snag` no idea what that is but I have a feeling that `skip_authorization_check` is not working appropriately since I see a "residents" query then redirection it appears that the `:redirect_residents` part of your authorization/authentication chain is the one redirecting. Maybe post that code as well since it appears very pertinent to the issue

Comment: You should use the association on your parent model and the id param from the URL. Do: `@parent.comments.new(...)` and `@snag_comments = @snag.comments`. Don't do `SnagComment.new(..., parent_id: 1)` or `SnagComment.where(snag_id: @snag.id)`. This is unrelated to your redirect problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed the most basic fundamental on how to setup a nested resource - nesting the route:

```
resources :snags do
  resources :snag_comments
end
```

This will make the "parent-child" relation part of the RESTful route and make it very clear what is going on VS implicitly passing that information in the form body.

```
class SnagCommentsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  before_action :set_snag

  # POST /snags/:snag_id/snag_comments
  def create
    @snag_comment = @snag.comments.new(snag_comment_params)
    if @snag_comment.save
      redirect_to @snag, notice: 'Comment created'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_snag
    @snag = Snag.find(params[:snag_id])
  end

  def snag_comment_params
    params.require(:snag_comment)
          .permit(:content, :image,:commenter, :first_name, :last_name)
  end
end
```

To create a form that posts to the nested route use an array:

```
def show
  @snag_attachments = @snag.snag_attachments
  @snag_comment = @snag.comments.new
  @snag_comments = @snag.comments
end
```

---

```
<%= simple_form_for([@snag, @snag_comment]) do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Make sure you remove the input for the parent ID. It is explicitly passed as segment in the URL.

Comment: Thank you :) . It turns out it was a routing / controller problem. I have the homeowner/admin sides and was trying to create a comment controller that they could both use, but it was redirecting as the homeowner didn't have the correct permissions. I had to nest the comment controllers separately, one under homeowner and one under admin - I've taking over a job that's been several years in the making so figuring out how to all works stumps me sometimes. A few hours staring at this issue turned out to be a ten minute fix.